# sql counting up records

Tags: sql

I have a table reservation that holds hotels, costumers, pricing etc

now i want to make a sum per hotel by calculating my pricing.

I already have a query working that calculates the price for every record but now i want to see it added up per hotel.

this is what i have:

```
select c.naam,((d.prijs+e.prijs+f.prijs)*(a.eind_datum - a.start_datum) )as sum 
from hotel c, kamer b, reservatie a, verblijfsformule d, verblijfsperiode e, kamertype f 
where a.kamerid = b.kamerid and b.hotelid = c.hotelid and a.verblijfsformuleid =   d.verblijfsformuleid and a.verblijfsperiodeid = e.verblijfsperiodeid and b.kamertypeid =   f.kamertypeid
```

if i run this query it gives me this result:

```
Name -           sum
Hilton antwerp - 2100
Hilton antwerp - 2250
Consequat      - 2000
consequat      - 1200
Hilton antwerp - 3000
```

so as you can see it gives the right sum but instead of only giving hilton antwerp and Consequat only 1 time and adding all those sums up per hotel it always gives it separately.

how can I resolve this problem ? 
I tried with a Group BY a.hotelid, that gave me the 2 hotels but only with the sum of the first record it didn't add up then.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.naam
    ,SUM((d.prijs+e.prijs+f.prijs)*(a.eind_datum - a.start_datum)) AS PriceSum
FROM hotel c
    INNER JOIN kamer b
        ON b.hotelid = c.hotelid
    INNER JOIN reservatie a
        ON a.kamerid = b.kamerid
    INNER JOIN verblijfsformule d
        ON a.verblijfsformuleid = d.verblijfsformuleid
    INNER JOIN verblijfsperiode e
        ON a.verblijfsperiodeid = e.verblijfsperiodeid
    INNER JOIN kamertype f
        ON b.kamertypeid = f.kamertypeid 
GROUP BY c.naam
```

Comment: after changing price sum = to as pricesum it works ! thanks man, need to wait 3 minutes before i can accept as answer tho

Comment: Great, I'll change it in the answer too.  I'm not sure what RDBMS system you are using or what version, but is obviously doesn't support the `PriceSum = ` syntax.  :)

Comment: using mysql maybe i should have noted that somewhere thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `group by` clause.

Like this:

```
select c.naam,((d.prijs+e.prijs+f.prijs)*(a.eind_datum - a.start_datum) )as sum 
  from hotel c, kamer b, reservatie a, verblijfsformule d, 
       verblijfsperiode e, kamertype f 
 where a.kamerid = b.kamerid
   and b.hotelid = c.hotelid 
   and a.verblijfsformuleid =   d.verblijfsformuleid 
   and a.verblijfsperiodeid = e.verblijfsperiodeid 
   and b.kamertypeid =   f.kamertypeid
 group by c.naam
```

That's it.

Comment: if i use that group by it gives me the 2 hotels but only with the sum of the first record it doesn't add up then

Comment: when i try that query i gives me this result: consequat - 2000 and hilton antwerp - 2100

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause.  `SELECT`....`GROUP BY hotelid`.